# If :a has_many :b and :b has_many :c, can we render :c via :a with JSON / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

There are 3 nested models (see model files at bottom)

- :user
- :quiz,
- :question

Is it possible to render `questions` via `user`?

**It is** possible to render `quizzes` via `user`. But I don't know why each quizzes' questions are not also included...

1. `{{user}}` renders that user's quizzes

> {"id":1,"email":"example@example.com","username":"jim","quizzes":[{"id":1,"name":"quiz1","user_id":1},{"id":2,"name":"quiz2","user_id":1},]}

2. But `{{user.quizzes}}` only renders quizzes, **and not those quizzes' questions**.

> [{"id":1,"name":"quiz1","user_id":1},{"id":2,"name":"quiz2","user_id":1}]

3. Also, `{{user.questions}}` will render a blank array, `[]`.

So there is a missing connection between `users` and `questions`, or maybe its only possible to render objects that are 1 level down?

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :quizzes 

  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: [:quizzes, :questions]))
  end
end
```

**quiz.rb**

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions

    def as_json(options = {})
        super(options.merge(include: [:user, :questions]))
    end    
end
```

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user    
    belongs_to :quiz

    def as_json(options = {})
        super(options.merge(include: [:user, :quiz]))
    end
end
```

Bear in mind I'm not super experienced with databases. Any advice would be very appreciated.

==============

## **UPDATE**

==============

Schema added below.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do

  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "ask"
    t.string   "answer"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "quiz_id"
    t.integer  "easy_count"
    t.integer  "diff_count"
  end

  add_index "questions", ["quiz_id"], name: "index_questions_on_quiz_id"
  add_index "questions", ["user_id"], name: "index_questions_on_user_id"

  create_table "quizzes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "quizzes", ["user_id"], name: "index_quizzes_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to connect `User` directly to `Question`, as opposed to indirectly through `Quiz`?

Comment: I'm trying to render aggregate question data, per quiz, on `site.io/users/:id` page. So I could do something like `ng-repeat="quiz in quizzes"` and then render `{{quiz.questions}}`, but that also renders nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although I am not 100% sure, but I think you did not create the relationship correctly. I guess `user.questions` gives you a blank array, because in your database, `questions` is only related to `quiz`. if you can, can you provide your database schema?

=================

## update

I create a database exactly following your schema, below is the example result I got after running `User.first.as_json`

`{"id"=>1, "email"=>"", "encrypted_password"=>"", "reset_password_token"=>nil, "reset_password_sent_at"=>nil, "remember_created_at"=>nil, "sign_in_count"=>0, "current_sign_in_at"=>nil, "last_sign_in_at"=>nil, "current_sign_in_ip"=>nil, "last_sign_in_ip"=>nil, "created_at"=>Sat, 02 Apr 2016 05:42:33 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sat, 02 Apr 2016 05:42:33 UTC +00:00, "username"=>nil,
   "quizzes"=>[{"id"=>1, "name"=>nil, "user_id"=>1, "created_at"=>Sat, 02 Apr 2016 05:42:42 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sat, 02 Apr 2016 05:42:42 UTC +00:00}], 
   "questions"=>[{"id"=>1, "ask"=>nil, "answer"=>nil, "created_at"=>Sat, 02 Apr 2016 05:43:11 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sat, 02 Apr 2016 05:43:11 UTC +00:00, "user_id"=>1, "quiz_id"=>1, "easy_count"=>nil, "diff_count"=>nil}]}`

## update 2

a quick fix will be

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :quizzes

  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: [quizzes: {include: :questions}]))
  end
end
```

but again as you see, using `include` and override as_json is very ugly. I suggest you eventually switch to Jbuilder or [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)

Comment: I've added the schema.

Comment: I tried to create a database exactly copy paste your schema, but I can fetch the questions without any problem, I m suspecting your database has some problem there, can you try to run `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`, and try again? see `user.questions` work or not

Comment: and as Matt said, you probably want to use [ActiveModelSerializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) or [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to render date for nested models, it's way more clean then using `include`

Comment: After a few small changes, `user.questions` works, but what I need is more like `quiz.questions` for `quiz in user.quizzes`, so I can extract aggregated question-data on a quiz level.

Comment: a quick fix will be change `super(options.merge(include: [:quizzes, :questions]))` to `super(options.merge(include: [quizzes: {include: :questions}]))`. but as your app grows, this solution will become really hard to deal with later.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to use has_many through because your questions are linked to the quizzes, not to the user.
Actually all your troubles comes to the fact you put user_id to question and to quizz.
Assuming your questions belongs to a quizz which belongs to a user, you should put user_id only in the quizz.

With no data repetition, you ensure no weird states where a question belongs to a quizz which doesn't belongs to the same user than the question (!)

And use delegate method to access the user id.

Here an improvement:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quizzes 
  has_many :questions, through: quizzes

  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: [:quizzes, :questions]))
  end
end

class Quizz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  belongs_to :user
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quizz
  delegate :user, to: :quizz
end
```

Comment: This allowed me to do `user.questions` but I was hoping to do something more like `quiz.questions` for `quiz in user.quizzes`, to display aggregated `question` data on a `quiz` level. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure you can do exactly what you said!
`user.quizzes.includes(:questions).each do |quizz| quizz.questions end`. Don't forget the includes, which prevent from N+1 request behavior (potentially performance costly)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a more robust solution like [ActiveModelSerializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email
  has_many :quizzes, serializer: QuizSerializer
end

class QuizSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name
  has_many :questions, serializer: QuestionSerializer
end

class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :ask, :answer
end

class UserController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render json: user, serializer: UserSerializer
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As Yacine pointed out, `has_many :through` is likely a better solution, so you don't have duplicate `user_id` in both `quizzes` and `questions` tables.

If you do make the changes, you can also remove the `user_id` column from `questions` table.